# How to color 2.5 and 97.5 intervals using ggplot and geom_ribbon?

Tags: r

I have the following code and need to color intervals. I think geom_ribbon could do it but I couldn't make it to work. Thanks.

```
 # trying geo-ribbon
    library(data.table)
    library(tidyverse)
#plot
fly <- fread("fly.summary", stringsAsFactors = F, data.table = F)
colnames(fly) <- c("mutation_per_site",     "n_estimation",          "theta_per_site_median", "theta_per_site_2.5",   "theta_per_site_97.5","year", "Ne_median" ,"Ne_2.5","Ne_97.5", "Ne_12.5",  "Ne_87.5" )

min(fly$Ne_median)

# log scaled
ggplot() + geom_line(data = fly, aes(y = log10(Ne_median), x = log10(year), colour = "fly" )) + 
    geom_line(data = fly, aes(ymin = log10(Ne_2.5), x = log10(year), colour = "fly_bound" )) +
    geom_line(data = fly, aes(ymax = log10(Ne_97.5), x = log10(year), colour = "fly_bound" )) + 
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = "Ne_2.5", ymax = "Ne_97.5" + 1), fill = "fly") +
    geom_line(aes(y = log10(Ne_median)))
    theme_classic()
```

Current plot
[image: current plot]

What I aim for

[image: What I aim for]

**Edit:**
As asked by Allan, here is the link for dput(fly) output for one species. It is over 80 mb so I uploaded in mega.nz

[Link to the dput(fly)](https://mega.nz/file/1mBAmI6Z#Zuc4SXqyQW1_yAkLZcCy0_8kx6lOdLW66Ga07whym5E)

Edit 2: updated the code.

Edit 3: short dput nrow=200
[dput log](https://pastebin.com/raw/u5QmKVWh)

Comment: Hi Sven. It's going to be very difficult to give you a working solution without access to the data you are using. If you type `dput(fly)` into your console, then copy the output to your clipboard, you can edit your question and paste the clipboard into a code block. That will allow users here to demonstrate how to achieve the result you are looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Please retry *without* quoting the variable in geom_ribbon (`aes(ymin = "Ne_2.5", ...)') which makes them interpreted as character values not variable names.

Comment: @I_O I got this: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Ne_2.5' not found

Comment: Sven, the page where you made your 80MB available warns: "Please note: once the download is complete, the file will be deleted from our servers." (which makes it unavailable to other people trying to solve the issue). You could, instead, use `dput` with a minimal subsample of your data, e.g. using `dplyr::sample_n()`

Comment: Oh, I am sorry about that. I will fix it. thanks

Comment: Hi Sven. I managed to download the file, but it will not read into R because is was truncated at about 80Mb. Could you maybe just post a sample, like `dput(fly[sample(nrow(fly), 1000),]`?

Comment: Hi Allan, thank you for the follow up. I create for 200, as 1000 also was truncated. Thank you!